# Android Changing Shape of The Back Button

Tags: android, android-toolbar

The back button on the action bar of my app seems a little large.  When I hold my finger on it on my phone the button highlights and I can see the right side of it is rounded out pushing over the text.

[image]

How can I make the button square and move the text closer to the left side of the action bar instead of being more out to the middle?

Comment: try this to move text closer to left side android:layout_gravity="left"  and to make button square make one drawable xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a custom drawable for your Toolbar's back navigation icon

```
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back);
ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Or if you want precise decoration use a custom toolbar layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle">

        <!-- Left side layout-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_left_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/iv_left_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_left_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLength="30"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **toolbar** property for this

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

like this use in toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp" />
```